# How to display an image from django models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am currently learning to make a blog website using Django.On my index page I want that there should be thumbnails present for the blogs in list form with the image which I asked them to upload while creating the post. I grabbed all the posts from my Post model but I don't know how to grab the image.

Here is my index page:

```
<div class="container-fluid row" >
{%for post in post_list%}
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 bor">
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="{{...}}"  class="img-thumbnail" alt="...">
  <div class="caption">
    <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
    <p>Published on: {{post.published_date}}</p>
    <p><a href="{%url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk%}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Read</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
  </div>
```

I read several answers related to Model.objects.all thing but I can't really understand what and how to do? I am new to Django. Can anyone help me please??

Comment: I am not sure of your image field's name so generally, for images to show: `<img src="{{ post.image_field_name.url }}"  class="img-thumbnail" alt="...">`

Comment: My image field's name is profile_pic but when I try this I get error that attribute profile_pic has no url.

Comment: have you included the `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` in settings?